# How to configure sharing on a small Windows 10 network since HomeGroup is gone?

Tags: networking, windows-10, network-shares, homegroup, windows-10-v1803

This is apparently a [common](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/17c9ea7d-52df-4ef9-95fa-0a961d11bfa3/fix-for-cannot-access-nas-drives-sharefolder-is-not-accessible-or-quoterror-code?forum=w8itpronetworking) [problem](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/homegroup-is-gone-in-windows-10-version-1803/1aea6406-f574-4835-8e33-27677fa1d107) but I have not found a solution.  With the deprecation of HomeGroup after the release of Windows 10 version 1803, I cannot get two computers to maintain network sharing after reboot.

Based upon [Microsoft's tutorial](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4091368/windows-10-homegroup-removed), I did the following:

- Setup a WorkGroup and then right- clicked on folder to be shared.
- Select "Give Access To" ==> Specific People
- Specify the group to share with and privileges for same.
- I get the link and hit "Share."

The first time I open the other computer, the sharing works. Once I restart, the "guest" computer cannot access files on "host" computer.

I have checked firewall settings and have tried turning off and on network sharing (which seemed to work once but not a second time). I did notice that the "Give Access To" settings on the host computer seem to change upon reboot.

Is there a script I should be running as a *.bat file that executes upon startup? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is your question how to get HomeGroup back, or how to share now that it's gone? Editing your title to clarify what you are actually asking may help improve the chances you'll get a good answer.

Comment: Also, just searching "homegroup" brought this Microsoft document and includes sections on how you should now share files and devices: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4091368/windows-10-homegroup-removed

Comment: Finally, is this a business or a home environment?

Comment: I do not need HG just to share files. Is in a small business environment. Too small to justify a dedicated server. Just need to share one data file and some Word doc's.
.
You would think that link would do it, but it leads down a rat maze of links which do not resolve the problem.

Comment: Sharing between Windows 10 machines is relatively simple.  Take a look at the comments within [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1325940/650163).  It works perfectly on my home network utilizing Microsoft accounts, but the same configuration will work with local accounts as well provided that they exist on every machine with the same userid/password combination.  For your specific needs, you could easily setup your "host" system and then create a shortcut on each "client" machine to a share such as `\\Dell-Desktop\Public\Documents`

Comment: @Run5k, thanks, I will try this later today. I noticed your screenshots in the shared link were pre-1803. Have you installed 1803? If so, I assume you've encountered no problems?

Comment: No, I haven't installed version 1803.  I tend to be rather conservative with my Windows 10 configurations, so the machines on my home network are set to [defer Feature Updates](https://superuser.com/q/1199677/650163) by 4-5 months.

Comment: @Run5k, sorry, one more question that sounds stupid as I type it! You say "every machine [should have] same userid/password combination." So on both host and client machines, I create a user "Run5K" with password "runfast"? Or do I simply subscribe each machine to same MS WorkGroup?

Comment: Going forward I would suggest a better solution, rather than sharing from individual desktops, would be to create a central share source, either a cheap NAS or even an older computer with suitable backups. Then you can create a share and a username/pwd for that share on the source device, and then Map that share as a drive on each client device, which allows you to specify the username/pwd for the share.

Comment: Not at all! I like to tell my employees that *"none of us were born with a keyboard in our hands,"* and we all started learning about computers from the very beginning. As a result, every question is a good one!  Yes, if you are using local accounts (versus Microsoft or Domain accounts), you would potentially create create a user "Run5K" with the password "runfast" on the host *and* every client machine, while also ensuring that every computer was a member of the same workgroup. Create more local accounts as necessary. And honestly, I simply utilize the built-in `WORKGROUP` nomenclature.

Comment: @Run5k, setting up identical users on both computers did the trick. If you want to put your suggestion as an answer, I will check it off. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear it.  I will get to work on that.

Comment: @music2myear, I agree with your last comment, but this client is a bit penny wise and pound foolish, and as I remember, they use some proprietary software that balked at NAS drives for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the HomeGroup capability has been removed, sharing between Windows 10 machines is still relatively simple. It works perfectly on my home network utilizing Microsoft accounts, but the same configuration will also work with local accounts as well provided that they exist on every machine with the same user ID/password combination.

I am utilizing a generic `WORKGROUP` on my home network with Windows 10 Pro machines, and the key is to configure your settings within the **Network and Sharing Center** in the `Change advanced sharing settings` interface. I have included three screenshots (below) of the Advanced sharing settings interface from a Windows 10 Professional machine on my home network. If you configure your home workgroup in a similar fashion to mine, it should work the same way. Notice that both `network discovery` as well as `file and printer sharing` are turned **on** within the Private network profile, but they are turned **off** for the Public network profile. I also configured `Turn on password protected sharing` for all networks. Ultimately, everything works together quite well.

For your specific needs, you could easily setup your "host" system and then create a shortcut on each "client" machine to a share such as this:

```
\\Dell-Desktop\Public\Documents
```

[image: Private Network profile]
[image: Public Network profile]
[image: All Networks profile]

Answer (score 1):

Setting up identical users on each PC does work, but you should really be working with the Credential Manager in the Control Panel. First of all, a warning - if any of your PCs still think that they are connect to a HomeGroup, then you should get them to leave the HomeGroup, otherwise you will find that any changes that you make in the Credential Manager on that PC will be overwritten after a reboot, and set back to the HomeGroup settings. When you open the Credential Manager, you need to select the Windows Credentials tab. Basically in the Credential Manager, you get to provide one user code and password for each PC on your network that you would like to connect to. Note that it must be a user code that has a password, but it doesn't need to be a user code that actually logs on to that PC. Once you have done this, that will give your PC access to the other PC, and I am assuming that you have already setup the rest of the file sharing. If you have any problems with this, then please don't hesitate to get back to me.

Comment: I will investigate these options, @user8068006, thanks.