# Windows 10 networking. I can see other PC's but they cant see me

Tags: networking, windows-10

I got 5 windows 10 Computers under one wireless network, and connect nicely under Homegroup.

Then, the computer are getting slower and I decided to format each of them using windows 10s bootable usb stick, fresh from microsoft.

The problem is, when I formatted the PC, the PC can still see the other 4 in network, but all the other 4 PC cannot see it.

And the homegroup option also not available in the freshly formatted PC.

The PC is activated using the key that come with the PC, in BIOS.

Comment: Did you get all the drivers installed? Check device manager to be sure all drivers are installed.

Comment: All the driver installed by windows ..

Comment: The latest Windows 10 Feature Update (version 1803) [removed the HomeGroup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4091368/windows-10-homegroup-removed) function.

Comment: Ya Run5k..but sharing is still possible right..

Comment: Yes, absolutely.  We have addressed this specific issue before:  [How to configure sharing on a small Windows 10 network since HomeGroup is gone?](https://superuser.com/q/1328942/650163)

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Did you have any lingering questions?