# Windows 10: Despite file sharing being turned on, shared directory cannot be seen beyond computer

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, windows-10-v1803

I am dealing with a client's computer that needs to have a directory shared out so that the HP AIO printer can send scans to his computer.

- The computer is not on a domain, as the workgroup (the small business) has only two computers.
- The shared directory can be seen from the same computer, but not by any computer beyond that one.
- The computer *is* on the network, jut to make that clear. DHCP & can be pinged just fine.
- Network discovery and file sharing is turned on, even for guest networks.
- I have also tried to connect to the share both with and without the firewall running, no success either way.
- The share itself is a very simple one, with no username or password set and “Everyone” having full access.
- The NetBIOS name is short and clear.
- This is a brand-new computer with almost nothing additional on it.

Suggestions? From experience I know it’s not supposed to be this difficult… Either I am missing something big that suddenly cropped up in v1803, or something else is getting in the way.

Comment: Just to double-check, is this Home, Pro, or Enterprise, and [which version/build of Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/236195/how-to-find-out-which-build-and-version-of-windows-10-you-have/) are you currently using?  Are these machines utilizing the same `WORKGROUP` name?  When you have a few minutes to spare, it may be a good idea to read this Q&A:  [How to configure sharing on a small Windows 10 network since HomeGroup is gone?](https://superuser.com/q/1328942/650163)

Comment: Win10 Pro v1803. Don’t know about OS build (currently off-site). Same workgroup name (although the printer doesn’t seem to have workgroup name ability). The second link you gave is the one I was referencing while on-site with the client, as it came up high on a Google search. The fact that file sharing still isn’t exposed to the network, even after confirming all those settings, is where I am stumped.

Comment: Have you tried testing it with the `%SystemDrive%\Users\Public\Downloads` folder?

Comment: From what I recall, the computer as a whole is inaccessible remotely (from a file-sharing perspective), including all of the public folders (I tried accessing \\{IP} without success from the other computer in the office). And yet, all the correct settings are turned on and this issue persists even when the firewall is turned off.

Comment: That is mysterious. Have you ensured that it isn't being affected by third-party security software on that machine?  It's also possible that this computer has been affected by the recent changes to the [availability of the SMBv1 protocol](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4034314/smbv1-is-not-installed-by-default-in-windows).  If that's the case, you could try to [enable the SMBv1 protocol](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/107605-enable-disable-smb1-file-sharing-protocol-windows.html) to see if it alleviates the problem.

Comment: Try specifying the path following UNC conventions, i.e. \\COMPUTER_NAME\Shared_Folder_Name\, if that can be done at the printer. Test that from another PC.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, from windows 10 1709 the SMB over NETBT, has been removed.I think it means that if you only want to use the 139 to share the folder, it will fail. So,make sure that the tcp port 445 is not blocked.

Meanwhile, if you can see the sharing files by \ip or \hostname. make sure that the following services are running, so that you can see them in network.
1. `Function Discovery Provider Host`  (remote pc want to see the sharing on the network)
2. `Function Discovery Resource Publication` (local PC published the sharing folder)