# Local network: Windows 10 machine not visible in Windows 7 Explorer

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-10

I have a local Network with a Window 10 computer and a Windows 7 computer.
Both have the same Network Settings (visible to other computers, etc.).

On the Windows 10 computer, I can see both the Windows 10 computer and the Windows 7 computer in the Windows Explorer Network Group, but on the Windows 7 computer, I don't see the Windows 10 computer.

The Windows 10 computer runs Windows 10 Pro, Version 1803, Build: 17134.285

The Windows 7 computer runs Windows 7 Home Premium, Version 6.1, Build 7600

What might be the reason for that?

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User!  Before you do anything else, it may be prudent to ensure that your [Windows 10 machine is configured properly](https://superuser.com/a/1329220/650163) within your `WORKGROUP`.

Comment: So the Windows 10 computer is the DESKTOP-5SD3VS3 computer?

Comment: If so, it is also possible that this Windows 10 computer has been affected by the recent changes to the [availability of the SMBv1 protocol](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4034314/smbv1-is-not-installed-by-default-in-windows). If that's the case, you could try to [enable the SMBv1 protocol](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/107605-enable-disable-smb1-file-sharing-protocol-windows.html) to see if it alleviates the problem.

Comment: I have disabled SMBv1 now (it was enabled), but that didn't help.

Comment: @Run5k I follow you "configured properly" link, and I turned off Network visibility for "Public", and now it works. I'm baffled that this solved the problem, because my active profile was "Private / Home", and not "Public". Could you make your comment the answer?

Comment: If that's the case, your question is essentially a duplicate of the one that I referenced.  As a result, it isn't really appropriate to submit the same answer, so I will mark this one as a duplicate accordingly.  One way or another, I'm glad to hear that your problem was resolved!

Comment: @Run5k Thank you so much, you've helped me a LOT!

Comment: @Run5k Could you still explain why the non-active profile affects this behaviour?

Comment: Theoretically. it shouldn't.  However, without an opportunity to scrutinize the entire configuration in-person, there are several potential factors in the equation that could affect the overall outcome.  Since you aren't utilizing the `Public` network profile (and should probably leave it in the current configuration for security purposes), I wouldn't worry about it too much.