# 2 computers in local network only see their shared Media but no other folders

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, network-shares

I have 2 computers, both running Windows 10 Pro Build 17134 (sbmv1 disabled).

They are set according to the 3 screenshots shown in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1328942/how-to-configure-sharing-on-a-small-windows-10-network-since-homegroup-is-gone).

However, both computers don't show anything in "Networks" in Windows Explorer.

Only when I enable Media sharing for one of them, the other computer becomes visible in the other computer's Windows Explorer. Windows Explorer then lists the shared Media. But other shared folders (yes, they are mapped to drives) don't show up.

What might be the issue here why the other shared folders are not shown in Windows Explorer?

Pinging each other works.

Computer B's Ethernet connection says 
"IPv4 connectivity: Internet"
"IPv6 connectivity: No Network Access"

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that although the folder was shared with "Everyone", "Everyone" was not a member of the list in "Security".
Once I added it, the folder was accessible.

Here is a screenshot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFgkc.png)

Stupid Microsoft didn't allow culture-indipendent keywords, so I couldn't add "Everyone", but "Jeder" (the same word in my language), so don't be suprised by that.
Italian users will have to use "Tutti" (the same word in their language). :-)